# URL in CMS block for search results page adds a forward slash

Tags: magento-1.9, url, cms

I'm creating a CMS block with a URL in there that's really just a search query

```
<a href ="{{store url="catalogsearch/result/?q=animals"}}">Find Animals</a>
```

For some reason the URL that gets outputted is

```
www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=animals/
```

when it should be

```
www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=animals
```

why is the extra forward slash being added at the end of the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<a href ="{{store url="catalogsearch/result/" _query="q=animals"}}">Find Animals</a>
```